# VueJS/VueX : Watch never called when state property is an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a simple flow that consist to:

- Call a VueX action to store multiple cars on backend side
- Call a mutation to store new cars just created
- Declare a watch that should be called each time the array of cars i changed

Problem is that my watcher is never called on my component.

**VueX module:**

```
/*
 * State: properties to store
 */
const state = {
    siteCars: []
};

/*
 * Getters: Getters of properties defined in state
 */
const getters = {

    siteCars(state) {
        return state.siteCars;
    }

};

/*
 * Mutations (Setters): Setters of properties defined in state
 */
const mutations = {

    PUSH_CARS(state, data) {
        state.siteCars = _.merge(state.siteCars, data.cars);
    },

};

/*
 * Actions
 */
const actions = {

    /*
     * Action used to create multiple cars
     */
    massImportCars({ commit, rootState }, payload) {

        axiosBackend.post("/cars/massimport", payload,
            {
                headers: { Authorization: rootState.auth.authString }
            }
        ).then(res => {

            commit("PUSH_CARS", {
                cars: res.data.data
            });

        }).catch(error => {});

    },

};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
};
```

**In my Vue Component:**

I just declared a watcher on my siteCars property which come from a getter inside the VueX module. Problem is that the handler is never called when new cars are pushed to the siteCars state.

```
watch: {
   siteCars: {
      handler(val){
         console.log("NEVER CALLED !!");
      },
      deep: true
   }
},
computed: {
   ...mapGetters(["siteCars"]),
},
```

Comment: Problem fixed ! It was because `_merge` function return an object! I just replace `_merge` with a standard `concat` javascript. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your mutation as

```
state.siteCars.push(data.cars);
```

so it doesn't change the reference of your previous state

Answer (score 1):

if you need to merge 2 arrays, solution with **ES6** spread operator

```
state.siteCars = [...state.siteCars, ...data.cars];
```